# What is the format of this datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have this format :

```
date = '2020-12-29 11:00:00+00:00'
```

I thought at the beginning the format is something like that `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`

But I don't have the `+00:00`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Your date/time string's format is compliant with [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), with space as a date/time separator. The `+00:00` is a UTC offset; all zeros mean it's UTC. You can parse conveniently with `datetime.fromisoformat`, e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-12-29 11:00:00+00:00')

print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 29, 11, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value for UTC offset

represent it using `%z`

more information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes